# How to achieve straight shadow with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm looking to achieve an odd shadow. With my (clearly)awesome photoshop skills, I need it to not  look like this [image: like this]

And look like this; [image: it looks like]

Basically I want it to look like 2d-lighting rather than lifted off the page.

Borders won't be a good solution, unless I'm able to blur them

Comment: Post your tried style here that made question even more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the css like this:

```
box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 1px 1px,
           rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px 2px,
           rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 3px 3px;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/keinwang/9ZjUp/1/embedded/result/)
For more details,click[#box-shadow](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow)